# Beginner android developer - having difficulty with layouts

Tags: android, layout, button, scrollview

I have a button that's below a `ScrollView`, the button is set to align to the parents bottom. The scroll view is set to `wrap_content` for its height. Once the `ScrollView` is filled with content it appears beneath the button. How can I set it to not go behind the button, for the `ScrollView`to end when the button begins?

I've tried placing `android:layout_below` in the bottom button, and when that didn't work I tried `layout_above` in the `ScrollView` for above the button. That last one caused my app to crash on start, no idea why. The first one once the `ScrollView` is longer than the screen it causes the button to be placed underneath with no way to access it.

Here's my XML file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_query"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/queryPromt"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_tag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_query"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/saveButton"
        android:hint="@string/tagPrompt"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText_query"
        android:text="@string/save" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_taggedSearches"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/saveButton"
        android:layout_below="@id/saveButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#666"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/taggedSearches"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_query"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView_taggedSearches"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout_query"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_clearTags"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/clearTags" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use layout_weight for this. If you set layout_height to "0px" you can use layout_weight to distribute the remaining parent space between sibling items.

In this case you want the button to have its normal size, and the scrollview to occupy whatever space remains. This should give you the general idea:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="0px"
     android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is basically what was suggested above, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
android:layout_below="@id/scrollView_query"
```

to the last button

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but once the scroll view gets longer than the screen the button is placed below the screen where you can't access it. I'd like for the button to be always at the bottom of the screen and the scroll view you scroll through it above the clear button.

Comment: Then consider using a linear layout with a fixed separator point and embed the scroll view in the upper and button in lower, so button position will be fixed and the scroll view can flow out of the allocated part of screen.

Comment: I tried doing an internet search for fixed separator point, but didn't find anything on it? Haven't learned about that yet. Is there anyway I can just set the ScrollView to match the parent, minus the button?

Comment: @Emrys90 Put the ScrollView in a LinearLayout, and the Button in a LinearLayout. To get the right heights, set the Button LinearLayout height to wrap_content and the ScrollView LinearLayout's height to 0dp with a defined layout_weight (any arbitrary layout weight will be sufficient).

Answer (score 0):

I did this before in my project. and here is my xml code. you can modify it as per your usage.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
     <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="This text view should act as header  " />
     <ScrollView android:layout_marginBottom="50dip" android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
          <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/RadioGroup01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />
               <RadioButton android:id="@+id/RadioButton11" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Radio Button....." />       
          </RadioGroup>
     </ScrollView>
     <RelativeLayout android:layout_marginTop="-50dip" android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1">
         <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="One"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Two" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Three" android:layout_gravity="right"/>
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```